# Is it better to save bitmaps to Sqlite Databse or Files handling its paths in Database ? - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao, greendao3

Is Converting bitmaps to byte[] and saving it to Database better performance and management or saving the bitmaps to Files and handling the paths in the Database ?

By better I mean as performance and management.

I have started a new application and i want to know if anybody has faced such a problem, and which solution is preferable for **Android** apps ?

**Note:** I am using Greendao as ORM.

Comment: the possible duplicate suggestion talked about anything but Android which is my main topic.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use files and manage them using some library like `Picaso` and storing paths in `DB`. 
`Android` have a lot of stuff related to [optimization](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) of bitmap usage by applying [caching](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html), [LRU](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) etc. You can be very specific in configuration and optimizing it. In addition to that - `sqlite` (as GreenDAO built on top of it) is in-memory database, you will simply run out of memory.